# Phonegap on Android: push notifications do nothing when tapped

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, testflight, pushwoosh

I had two devices with the same application installed (PhoneGap 2.5.0, Android SDK min 11, target 19).  One worked perfectly and the other had the following issue: I sent a push notification (via PushWoosh, http://pushwoosh.com/ similar to Urban Airship) to all devices and both my devices received it, but on the device with the issue, when the application was not in the foreground and I tapped on the notification from the tray, the notification was dismissed but the application was not brought back into the foreground.

The only difference between the two devices was that one (the working one) had only received the app via local builds out of Eclipse and Android Studio and the other (the one with the issue described above) had received the app from local builds and TestFlight (http://testflightapp.com build management service).

I tried installing the app via TestFlight on the working device and now that device exhibits the same issue.  I've tried uninstalling TestFlight and my app and then building to each device from Android Studio, but the issue persists.

### Logcat

In Android Studio, logcat tells me the following as soon as I tap on the notification:

```
12-24 17:01:25.152     780-1032/? I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {flg=0x24000000 cmp=com.markon.markon/com.arellomobile.android.push.PushHandlerActivity bnds=[0,153][1080,351] (has extras)} from pid -1
12-24 17:01:25.152     780-1032/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x24000000 cmp=com.markon.markon/com.arellomobile.android.push.PushHandlerActivity bnds=[0,153][1080,351] (has extras) } from null (pid=-1, uid=10207) not exported from uid 10217
12-24 17:01:25.172     780-1032/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Unable to send startActivity intent
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x24000000 cmp=com.markon.markon/com.arellomobile.android.push.PushHandlerActivity bnds=[0,153][1080,351] (has extras) } from null (pid=-1, uid=10207) not exported from uid 10217
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1186)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:741)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityInPackage(ActivityManagerService.java:3300)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.sendInner(PendingIntentRecord.java:252)
        at com.android.server.am.PendingIntentRecord.send(PendingIntentRecord.java:192)
        at android.content.IIntentSender$Stub.onTransact(IIntentSender.java:64)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

### Possibly related issue with TestFlight

Before I uninstalled TestFlight, device registration with PushWoosh was acting odd.  I built a settings page where users could opt in/out of push notifications which calls the relevant service in PushWoosh.  Logcat said that the call was happening correctly and even returned a successful callback, but the setting never stuck.  If I was opted in (device registered) and I opted out, then PushWoosh would report via logcat that the call was successful but the count of registered devices wouldn't update and push notifications still came through.  The opposite (being opted out and then trying to opt in) failed in the same way.

As soon as I uninstalled TestFlight, my app and reinstalled my app, the service invocations to register/unregister my device worked perfectly.  However, even after this, tapping the push notifications failed in the same way.  I can't figure out how to fully "reset" my phone to get back to the state I was in before (where everything worked with push notifications).

### AndroidManifest.xml

I don't think is related since I didn't modify the manifest between the time when everything was working well and when the issue began.  Including just in case though.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.markon.markon"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<compatible-screens></compatible-screens>
    <supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 

<!-- start pushwoosh needs -->
<!--library-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>

<!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<!--
Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages.

NOTE: the permission *must* be called PACKAGE.permission.C2D_MESSAGE,
    where PACKAGE is the application's package name.
-->
<permission
     android:name="com.markon.markon.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
     android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission
     android:name="com.markon.markon.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
<uses-permission
     android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<!-- end pushwoosh needs -->


    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Markon"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_markon"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >
            <!-- for pushwoosh -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.markon.markon.MESSAGE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- for pushwoosh -->
        <activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushWebview"/>
        <activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.MessageActivity"/>
        <activity android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushHandlerActivity"/>

        <!--
          BroadcastReceiver that will receive intents from GCM
          services and handle them to the custom IntentService.
         
          The com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND permission is necessary
          so only GCM services can send data messages for the app.
        -->
        <service android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.PushGCMIntentService"/>
        <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />

                <category android:name="com.markon.markon"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
         
        <!--
          Application-specific subclass of PushGCMIntentService that will
          handle received messages.
        -->
        <!-- <service android:name="com.arellomobile.android.push.GeoLocationService"/> -->

    </application>

</manifest>
```